# i cant pub get flutter_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml

```
Because no versions of google_fonts match >3.0.1 <4.0.0 and google_fonts 3.0.1 depends on path_provider ^2.0.0, google_fonts ^3.0.1 requires path_provider ^2.0.0.
And because flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.7 depends on path_provider ^1.1.0, google_fonts ^3.0.1 is incompatible with flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.7.
So, because brain_school depends on both flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer ^1.0.7 and google_fonts ^3.0.1, version solving failed.}
 i get this error whene i try to pub get flutter_pdf_viewer
```

i cant pub get flutter_pdf_viewer

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your pub packages, you can use theses version

```dart
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  flutter_pdf_viewer: ^0.0.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.13
```